# Parsing Command line Args after run

Tags: c++

Someone on a forum was looking how to parse command line arguments after running program. And people provided him with:

```
WCHAR * szCmdLine = L"insert x";
WCHAR ** argv;
int argc;

argv = CommandLineToArgvW(szCmdLine, &argc);
```

And it works... accept it only works with what I can put in the L"insert x";
How do I get the input, and then set WCHAR * szCmdLine equal to the char/string that was entered?

if I create a char called cmd, and try to get the input of it, and do

```
WCHAR * szCmdLine = cmd;
```

then it gives the error:

```
source.cpp|18|error: cannot convert 'char*' to 'WCHAR* {aka wchar_t*}' in initialization|
```

I just want to get custom input for the command.
 Sorry if this is a stupid question...

Comment: it is unclear what you want.

Comment: Ugh... I know it is... let me edit my question

Comment: That error should be pretty self-explanatory if you only read it.`wchar_t` and `char` are two different types, and you can't convert from one to the other that simple. You have to use e.g. [`mbstowcs`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/multibyte/mbstowcs) to convert a narrow (`char`) string to a wide (`wchar_t`) string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand your intent (read data from standard input, and parse it like a command line) correctly, you want something on this general order:

```
std::wstring input;

std::wcout << L"Please enter arguments: ";
std::getline(std::wcin, input);

int argc;

wchar_t **argv = CommandLineToArgvW(input.c_str(), &argc);
```